# How to delete complete repository folder from GitHub (Public Account)

Tags: github, repository

I have one GitHub free account or we can say public account. 
I just want to know how we can delete the complete repository folder from GIT.

I have sourcetree setup to do all the changes to git.

Like I want to delete the highlighted repository. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To delete a repository on GitHub, follow the below steps.

1. Go to your repository
2. Click on Settings

[image]

3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and you would find the **Delete this repository** button as shown here

[image]

4. Click on **Delete this repository** and your repository will be deleted from GitHub

Comment: @vijaysahu could you please accept if this answered your query? Let me know if it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in to your GitHub account.
2. And then go inside the repository you want to delete.
3. Click 'Settings' next to the 'Insights'.
4. Scroll down the page until you see the section "Danger Zone". Then select the option 'Delete this repository".
5. Read the given details, and If you want to continue deleting, confirm the given statement inside "" and confirm access.
6. Finally, Your repository "" was successfully deleted.